# Blazor Server EF Core: created/modified at/by for all created/modified entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using the code below within my project. This works just fine, but where I am updating created/modified at I also have to update created/modified by. However, within my ApplicationDbContext I cannot use UserManager because this will cause circular dependency.

Any suggestions on how to add the created/modified by/at columns into ***every*** entity being created/updated are welcome. And every entity in bold text because when I update an entity with child element(s), these also need to be updated.

E.g: I have a `Debtor` with one or multiple `Contact`. The created/modified at/by columns of the `Contact` also need to be updated.

Thanks for the help!

***DebtorService:***

```
internal class DebtorService : IDebtorService
{

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public DebtorService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<ResponseModel> UpsertAsync(Debtor debtor)
    {
        try
        {

            if (debtor.Id > 0)
                _unitOfWork.Repository<Debtor>().Update(debtor);
            else
                await _unitOfWork.Repository<Debtor>().AddAsync(debtor);

            await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
            return ResponseModel.SuccessResponse(GlobalDeclaration._successResponse, debtor);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ResponseModel.FailureResponse(GlobalDeclaration._internalServerError);
        }

    }
    public async Task<ResponseModel> DeleteAsync(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var debtor = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Debtor>().Get(Id);
            if (debtor != null)
            {
                debtor.Deleted = true;
                await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
                return ResponseModel.SuccessResponse(GlobalDeclaration._successResponse, null);
            }
            else
                return ResponseModel.FailureResponse("Not Found");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ResponseModel.FailureResponse(GlobalDeclaration._internalServerError);
        }
    }

    public async Task<ResponseModel> GetAllAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var debtor = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Debtor>()
           .TableNoTracking
           .ToListAsync();
            return ResponseModel.SuccessResponse(GlobalDeclaration._successResponse, debtor);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ResponseModel.FailureResponse(GlobalDeclaration._internalServerError);
        }

    }
    public async Task<ResponseModel> GetByIdAsync(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var debtor = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Debtor>().Get(Id);
            if (debtor != null)
            {
                return ResponseModel.SuccessResponse(GlobalDeclaration._successResponse, debtor);
            }
            else
                return ResponseModel.FailureResponse("Not Found");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ResponseModel.FailureResponse(GlobalDeclaration._internalServerError);
        }
    }

}
```

***UnitOfWork:***

```
internal class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    IDbContextTransaction dbContextTransaction;
    private Hashtable _repositories;
    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        _repositories ??= new Hashtable();

        var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;

        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>);

            var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity)), _context);

            _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
        }

        return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
    }
    public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        dbContextTransaction?.Commit();
    }
    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        dbContextTransaction?.Rollback();
    }
    private bool disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        disposed = true;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

***Repository:***

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    protected DbSet<T> _entities;

    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected string GetFullErrorTextAndRollbackEntityChanges(DbUpdateException exception)
    {
        //rollback entity changes
        if (_context is DbContext dbContext)
        {
            var entries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

            entries.ForEach(entry =>
            {
                try
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            });
        }

        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return exception.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected virtual DbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                _entities = _context.Set<T>();

            return _entities;
        }
    }
    public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        await Entities.AddAsync(entity);
        return entity;
    }
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    public Task UpdateAsync(object Id, T entity)
    {
        T exist = _context.Set<T>().Find(Id);
        _context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(object id)
    {
        var entity = await Entities.FindAsync(id);
        if (entity == null)
            return false;

        Entities.Remove(entity);
        return true;
    }
    public async Task<bool> Delete(T entity)
    {
        Entities.Remove(entity);
        return true;
    }
    public async Task<bool> Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        var entities = Entities.Where(where);
        Entities.RemoveRange(entities);
        return true;
    }
    public async Task<T> Get(object id)
    {
        return await Entities.FindAsync(id);
    }
    public async Task<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return await Entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(where);
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Entities;
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return Entities.Where(where);
    }
    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public virtual void SaveAsync()
    {
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public virtual async Task<int> Count()
    {
        return await Entities.CountAsync();

    }
    public virtual async Task<int> Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return await Entities.CountAsync(where);

    }
    public virtual new DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Table => Entities;

    public virtual IQueryable<T> TableNoTracking => Entities.AsNoTracking();

}
```

***ApplicationDbContext:***

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Debtor> Debtors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }


    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {

        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseModel>())
        {

            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    //entry.Entity.CreatedBy = Guid.Parse(currentUser.Id);
                    entry.Entity.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    //entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = Guid.Parse(currentUser.Id);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    //entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = Guid.Parse(currentUser.Id);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Debtor>().Navigation(d => d.Contacts).AutoInclude();
    }

}
```

Comment: [Polite] You are using an infrastucture appropriate to the Server Side Rendering paradigm in an SPA.  You are implementing the IRepository and Unit of Work pattern over a framework [Entity Framework] that already implements those patterns.  I see a wall of code redoing what EF aleady does, but nowhere in your code where you use the DbContextFactory, which is a must in Async Blazor.  See articles such as this which might prompt a rethink - https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2018/02/20/ditch-the-repository-pattern-already/

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis do you know where to find an example project for Blazor Server using Individual Accounts as authentication type and Entity Framework Core?

I am trying to build a clean architecture for Blazor Server but don't get the CRUD functions to work as they should. For example, all the `Contacts` of my `Debtor` are not checked for updates/new items/deleted items. I just want to say _db.Update(debtor) and all the child elements are also added/updated/deleted when neccesary. And still using the above auditable columns (created by, created at, modified by, modified at).

Comment: ***alternatives for EF core and authentication type are also welcome***

Comment: Jeremy.  I'm not ignoring your comments.  It's just that trying to answer them is way, way beyond the scope of an SO answer.  I've travelled this road. My modern approach is outlined here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.OneWayStreet - which is almost several steps to far from where you are.    You need to start to understand *Aggregates* [Composite objects], and how to deal with them in the SPA context.  Do some reading on the topic.  For starters - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis your help is much appreciated! When I use the `DbContextFactory` I face another problem I tried to solve for a long time now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257390