# DbContextFactory: update not affecting child elements in Blazor Server project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Within my Blazor Server project I am using the following models:

***Debtor:***

```
public class Debtor : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string? ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string? InvoiceEmail { get; set; }
    public string? ChamberOfCommerce { get; set; }
    public bool MustPayRent { get; set; }
    public bool ConsumptionsViaInvoice { get; set; }
    public List<DebtorContact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

***DebtorContact:***

```
public class DebtorContact : Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Position { get; set; }
    public string? InvoiceEmail { get; set; }
    public int DebtorId { get; set; }
    public Debtor Debtor { get; set; }
}
```

I was told and learned that within Blazor Server you use a `DbContextFactory` instead of `DbContext`. So I use the code below to update my Debtor. When I add a new `DebtorContact` to my `Debtor`, this is added to the database with this update. However, when I delete a `DebtorContact`, this update does not delete this `DebtorContact`

```
public class DebtorService : IDebtorService
{

    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _context;

    public DebtorService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(Debtor debtor)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _db = _context.CreateDbContext())
            {
                _db.Set<Debtor>().Update(debtor);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the code below all my changes to the `Debtor` and child `DebtorContact`'s ***do*** get saved the correct way. Deleted `DebtorContact`'s get deleted. I still declare it as a `DbContextFactory` in my `program.cs`, but do not use `CreateDbContext()`.

```
public class DebtorService : IDebtorService
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DebtorService(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(Debtor debtor)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Set<Debtor>().Update(debtor);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

***What is the correct way within a Blazor Server project?*** How to get all (child) entities to update/delete when needed. How to get EF Core to see the changed entities and only update these entities. The first set of code updates all child entities when I hit save.

Comment: First variant is correct. Blazor Server do not use automatic scope creation, so your `DbContext` from second variant will be not disposed. Also for correct updating you have to load child entities with Include and update their properties manually. Also do not use `Update` method.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Update child element properties all manually? I have models with four or five many-to-many relationships. Doesn't entity framework core manage this for you?

Comment: Nope, you have to do that by yourself.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27177623/10646316)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Also, what are the consequences for using the second option I listed above? Are you gonna create security issues? Performance issues?

Comment: You will have memory leak. Context will be never disposed. Also it will fail in asynchronous calls. Please read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0#database-access), `DbContextFactory`  introduced exactly for blazor server.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, creating a new DbContext instance, with **using (var _db = _context.CreateDbContext())**, you create a new scope, so if you want to update your entities and also its childs, you must do your job inside this scope: load entities, load childs, modify them, and call SaveChanges(). All changes, including those on childs will be saved. And at the end, **_db** context will be correctly disposed.

In the second case, you already have the **_context** scope, so when you load, modify, etc.. and call SaveChanges(), all changes will be persisted on the database, but the context instance still remain active. It's not right so.

In other words, when you create a new context instance, **ChangeTracker** keeps track in memory of all changes made to database objects; by calling SaveChanges(), all changes will be written to the database. At the end, the context must be disposed, freeing up resources.